# Which parameters are needed to use GET verify_credentials Twitter API method?

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

i just need some help with Twitters' API

I used the sign in with twitter flow to get the tokens needed to make calls to the API, there weren't any problems with the implementation, and so far I have got both oauth_token and oauth_token_secret so I think I have what I need to use the API.

The problem is about the last method which the documentation said about verif credentials, I am supposed to use that GET method to get a json with information about the user which has just logged into twitter by my app, however, Twitter docu doesn't mention anything about what parameters I need to pass or what headers, just the url.

I used php curl to make the calls to the API, do you know what parameters I need to pass to the API to finally get the json?

Here you have the link to the API docu:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using php language? are you using any particular library?

Comment: Im using php and curl functions from php, not any third party library, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No params, just the 'Authorization' header.

Use the "OAuth Signature Generator" on the link you included to generate a test request and confirm yourself.

You just need to properly sign the request.  This provides the context including the user, since it implicitly includes details about your request, the client secret, the user token etc.

```
$ oksocial https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
{
  "id": 999999,
  "id_str": "999999",
  "name": "Bobby Bonson",
  "screen_name": "xxxx",
  "location": "CA",
  "description": "...",
  "url": null,
  "entities": {
    "description": {
      "urls": []
    }
  },
  "protected": false,
  "followers_count": 699,
  "friends_count": 631,
  "listed_count": 34,
```